# Test/Validate SCORM objects?

Tags: validation, testing, epub, scorm, checkvalidity

I maintain a large (~5000 document) repository of educationally-useful works. I am already packaging them as ePubs and would like to package them as SCORM objects as well. I've added basic SCORM features the to epubs I'm generating, but I'm finding the standard SCORM tools difficult to use to determine whether I'm getting it right. 
For ePubs validity, I used epubchecker( https://github.com/IDPF/epubcheck), which fulfilled the requirements quit well.

Can someone tell me whether there's a way to validate the SCORM object or
is out there any Library created suitable for SCORM validation?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but hopefully helpful: You might also want to consider adding Tin Can tracking to your ePubs so that your clients can get tracking data from that format too.

Answer (score 5):

The ADL test suite is the only official testing system. Unfortunately it's not very robust, and is known to be cranky. It's also Windows only.

In my experience, the best checker is SCORM Cloud over at scorm.com. It will test your package for conformance, and provides very detailed logs for troubleshooting.

It requires uploading to a 3rd party, so it won't be appropriate in some use cases. SCORM Cloud is free for testing purposes but costs money if deploying the courses to students.

Comment: Link to SCORM Cloud: https://cloud.scorm.com and to ADL conformance suite: http://www.adlnet.gov/resources/scorm-version-1-2-conformance-test-suite-version-1-2-7/

Comment: Also note that you might need to upgrade past the free account for SCORM Cloud if you want to upload packages totalling more than 100mb at any one time (you can delete packages to make space).

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. It was really helpfull.
Further I was thinking to develop a Scorm Editor, but I am not quite sure
if the SCORM Cloud would be my solution, to validate the created content, or to check if the content fulfills the scorm content requirements and is scorm-conformant.
Is still scorm cloud the best solution, or would be better first to check the structure tree, using functionality of any programming language, then to use SCORM cloud for compatibility? Or SCORM cloud can handle all those cases?